# SQLite select statment for windows phone apps

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-phone

I am creating an app for windows phone for which I need to create a database connection for that i have used SQLite.
From this Link i have executed the queries:http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/wp7/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-phone-application.htm

this is the code:

```
private void btncreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MySqlLiteDB == null)
    {
        MySqlLiteDB = new SQLiteConnection("MyTestDB");
        MySqlLiteDB.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection opened Successfully!!!");

    }
}

private void btnpopulate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SQLiteCommand cmd=MySqlLiteDB.CreateCommand("Create table student(id int primary key,name text,zipcode numeric(7))");
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int id = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        id++;
        string name = "Name" + id;
        int zipcode = 98000 + id;

        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into student(id,name,zipcode) values(" + id + ",\"" + name + "\"," + zipcode + ")";
      i =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }


    MessageBox.Show("Insert successful");

}

private void btnclear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SQLiteCommand cmd = MySqlLiteDB.CreateCommand("drop table student");
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data Cleared successfully");

}


private void btnclose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MySqlLiteDB != null)
    {
        MySqlLiteDB.Dispose();
        MySqlLiteDB = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Connection closed");

    }
}
```

but now i need to retrieve the data from database table and bind it to a grid using select statement how can i do this?
I want to show the table data in a grid is there any way to bind the data to a grid.

Answer (score 1):

Add  the following function and class in your code

```
public class student
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public long zipcode {get;set;}
}

SelectFromStudent()
{
    string query="select id,name,zipcode from student";
    List<student> studentList = SelectFromTable<student>(query);
}

List<T> SelectFromTable<T>(String statement) where T : new()
{
    SQLiteCommand cmd = MySqlLiteDB.CreateCommand(statement);
    var lst = cmd.ExecuteQuery<T>();
    return lst.ToList<T>();
}
```

You can't use grid bind data in windows phone application. there is another control to do such kind of operation ListBox. you can edit Itemtemplate of ListBox. ListBox has itemsource property.